# Electron "require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm making an application which I need to give access to the file system (fs) module, however even with `nodeIntegration` enabled the renderer gives me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

All similar problems I could find had a solution that said they needed to turn `nodeIntegration` on, however I already have it enabled.

This is my main.js:

```
const electron = require('electron');   
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;  

let win;

app.on('ready', () => {
    var { width, height } = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
    width = 1600;
    height = 900;
    win = new BrowserWindow({'minHeight': 850, 'minWidth': 1600, width, height, webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: true,
        webSecurity: true,
        nodeIntegration: true
    }});
    win.setMenu(null);
    win.loadFile('index.html');
    win.webContents.openDevTools()
});
```

My index.js, linked in index.html as `<script src="index.js"></script>` currently only has `require("fs");` in it, I've commented out all the other stuff.

I don't know why require still doesn't work even though `nodeIntegration` is enabled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you have `nodeIntegration` disabled but aren't using `contextIsolation`, you could use a preload script to expose a safe version of it on the global object. (Note: you shouldn't expose the entire `fs` module to a remote page!)

Here's an example of using a preload script in this way:

```
// main process script
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    contextIsolation: false,
    nodeIntegration: false,
    preload: './preload.js'
  }
})

mainWindow.loadURL('my-safe-file.html')



// preload.js
const { readFileSync } = require('fs')

// the host page will have access to `window.readConfig`,
// but not direct access to `readFileSync`
window.readConfig = function () {
  const data = readFileSync('./config.json')
  return data
}



// renderer.js
const config = window.readConfig()
```

If you're only loading local pages, and those pages don't load or execute unsafe dynamic content then you *might* reconsider the use of `contextIsolation` for this strategy. If you want to keep `contextIsolation` on, however (and you definitely should if you have a chance of showing unsafe content), you can only communicate with the preload script with [message passing via `postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Here's an example of the same scenario above, but with `contextIsolation` on and using message passing.

```
// main process script
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    contextIsolation: true,
    nodeIntegration: false,
    preload: './preload.js'
  }
})

mainWindow.loadURL('my-unsafe-file.html')



// preload.js
const { readFileSync } = require('fs')

const readConfig = function () {
  const data = readFileSync('./config.json')
  return data
}

window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.source !== window) return
  if (event.data.type === 'request') {
    window.postMessage({ type: 'response', content: readConfig() })
  }
})



// renderer.js
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.source !== window) return
  if (event.data.type === 'response') {
    const config = event.data.content
  }
})
window.postMessage('request')
```

While this is definitely more verbose and difficult to deal with (and forces things to be async, because message passing is async), it's also much more secure. A pair of small JS wrappers around the `postMessage` API could make this easier to work with (e.g. via an RPC-like mechanism), but remember that the whole point of using `contextIsolation` is because you can't trust the renderer, so your preload script shouldn't trust just any message it gets via the `postMessage` API — you should always verify the event that you receive to ensure that you trust it.

[This slide deck](https://doyensec.com/resources/Asia-19-Carettoni-Preloading-Insecurity-In-Your-Electron.pdf) describers in detail why turning off Node integration without using context isolation is not always a good idea.

Comment: Doesn't `contextIsolation: true` prevent reading of `window.readConfig` in the page/renderer?

Comment: @ford04 You are correct — I believe a bug allowed modification of `window` with `contextIsolation` on a while back. I've updated my answer to be more comprehensive.

Comment: The first example in this answer needs `contextIsolation: false` to work, as @ford04 suggests.