# Electron Require is Not Defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

**`electron =  7.1.8`**
**`node = v12.14.1`**

I'm learning JS as a side project and trying to get a hang of using Electron. Below is my code for `index.js`

**index.js**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = reqiure('path');

const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

let mainWindow;

// Listen for the app to be ready

app.on('ready', function(){
    // Create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ 
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
    // Load html in window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dashboard.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes:true
    }));
});
```

here is my `dashboard.html`

**dashboard.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
    require('./main.js')
 </script>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>Heat Tracker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Heat Tracker</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

When running it each time, in get the error:

```
electron .


App threw an error during load
ReferenceError: reqiure is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mirko\Desktop\heat-tracker\main.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648:12)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at loadApplicationPackage     (C:\Users\Mirko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:109:16    )
    at Object.<anonymous>     (C:\Users\Mirko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:155:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:30)
```

I have looked everywhere to try and fix this but I have been stuck for the last hour. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const path = require('path');
```

use require not reqiure there a spelling mistake

Comment: wow am i stupid thank you

Answer (score 0):

To use `require` you must set `nodeIntegration` to `false`

Comment: I have set `nodeIntegration` to `false` and it still gives me that error.

Comment: look here some usage examples https://stackoverflow.com/a/54560886/7196144

Answer (score 0):

@goodknight : if you really want to learn electron. then you must look at this basic project and play around 
https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start 
 Iam sure you will be benefited.